# How to select element by its body contents?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have the following element in my page:

```
<u>abc123</u>
```

How to select that element and change its contents 'abc123' to something else?

What I am actually trying to do is adding an iframe in between `<u></u>`. I know it is kind of silly, but I have a special requirement for that.

A second question: Is it possible to substitute the whole thing (`<u>abc123</u>`) for the iframe, or the iframe tag must go in between the `<u></u>`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter by content (example):

```
$("u").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "abc123";
}).html("<iframe>");
```

To directly execute code:

```
$("u").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.text() == "abc123"){
        $this.html("<iframe>");
    }
})
```

Use `.replaceWith()` instead of `.html()` if you want to also replace the tags (`<u></u>`).

The `.html()` method overwrites the current contents of an element. If you want to add new information without erasing the previous data, use `.append()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the element with an iframe this way (this is straight JavaScript, but you can do that in jQuery also):

```
<u id="test"></u>

var e = document.getElementById('test');
var iFrame = [...];

e.parentNode.insertBefore(iFrame, e);
e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can add content to your   using the Text() function .

```
$("u").text(yourText);
```

for selecting the element by its content

```
$("u").each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).text()=="abc123"){
     //do what you want
}
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**JS**

```
$("u").html('<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="300" height="300">Alternative context</iframe>');
```